# Retrieve authentication data successfully with webview2

Tags: c#, webview, google-oauth

context : I created a windows service which will retrieve emails and place them in the folders provided for this purpose and you have to authenticate, but google has to disable the token option via embeddedview, so i made a winfor with a `webview2`
and I override `LocalServerCodeReceiver.OpenBrowser`to do `webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(_urlAuth);`
my problem is that in

`private void WebView_CoreWebView2ResponseReceived(object sender,CCoreWebView2WebResourceResponseReceivedEventArgs e)`

I don't know which catch part tells me that my authentication is successful

Do you have an idea of the header which tells me that authentication to my API is ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for asking, but after 4 hours of searching I found it.
it was necessary to do

```
    private readonly string _urlAuth = string.Empty;
    private readonly string _redirectUri = string.Empty;

    public FormWebView(string urlAuth, string redirectUri)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _urlAuth = urlAuth;
        _redirectUri = redirectUri;
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync(Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2 wv, string webCacheDir = "")
    {
        CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions options = null;
        string tempWebCacheDir = string.Empty;
        CoreWebView2Environment webView2Environment = null;

        //set value
        tempWebCacheDir = webCacheDir;

        //if webCacheDir isn't specified, create it in the users temp folder
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tempWebCacheDir))
        {
            //get fully-qualified path to user's temp folder
            tempWebCacheDir = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();

            //create a unique folder name in the user's temp folder
            //by using NewGuid to generate a folder name, a new folder will
            //be createed each time. If this is undesired, specify a folder name
            tempWebCacheDir = System.IO.Path.Combine(tempWebCacheDir, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
        }

        webView2Environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, tempWebCacheDir, options);

        //wait for CoreWebView2 initialization
        await wv.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(webView2Environment);
    }

    private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webView.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += WebView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;

        await InitializeAsync(webView);
    }

    private void CoreWebView2_NavigationStarting(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Uri.StartsWith(_redirectUri))
        {
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void WebView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //set properties
        webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled = false;
        webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDevToolsEnabled = false;
        webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.IsZoomControlEnabled = false;

        webView.CoreWebView2.NavigationStarting += CoreWebView2_NavigationStarting;

        webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(_urlAuth);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**